# Changing animation state in bottom navigation bar while clicking back button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I have used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble_bottom_bar) bottom navigation bar library in my app and it works perfectly. But i want to maintain a **back navigation** with the back button in android phones like for example in the Google Play Store bottom navigation where if we navigate through the bottom navigation the animation changes and also if we navigate back through the back button the animation changes the way before.

I have tried [this](https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-navigating-off-the-charts-e118562a36a5) article which is somewhat doing what i want but the animations are not working.

This is my stateful widget where my bottom nav bar is,

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int currentIndex;
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    currentIndex = 0;
  }

  void changePage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
      body:
        new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Offstage(
              offstage: currentIndex != 0,
              child: new TickerMode(
                enabled: currentIndex == 0,
                child: new MaterialApp(home: new HomePage()),
              ),
            ),
            new Offstage(
              offstage: currentIndex != 1,
              child: new TickerMode(
                enabled: currentIndex == 1,
                child: new MaterialApp(home: new StayPage()),
              ),
            ),
            new Offstage(
              offstage: currentIndex != 2,
              child: new TickerMode(
                enabled: currentIndex == 2,
                child: new MaterialApp(home: new TravelPage()),
              ),
            ),
            new Offstage(
              offstage: currentIndex != 3,
              child: new TickerMode(
                enabled: currentIndex == 3,
                child: new MaterialApp(home: new MorePage()),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

      floatingActionButton: Visibility(
        visible: _isVisible,
        child: Container(
          height: 100.0,
          width: 85.0,
//        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {});
              },
              elevation: 20.0,
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              label: Text(
                "Plan",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "OpenSansBold",
                ),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,

      bottomNavigationBar: Visibility(
        visible: _isVisible,
        child: BubbleBottomBar(
          hasInk: true,
          fabLocation: BubbleBottomBarFabLocation.end,
          opacity: .2,
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          onTap: changePage,
          elevation: 15,
          items: <BubbleBottomBarItem>[
            BubbleBottomBarItem(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                activeIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Home",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                  ),
                )),

            BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.hotel,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.hotel,
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
              title: Text(
                "Stay",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.card_travel,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.card_travel,
                color: Colors.indigo,
              ),
              title: Text(
                "Travel",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.more,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.more,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              title: Text(
                "More",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It is not necessary that i have to use this library, i just want to implement a bottom navigation bar and when navigating back through using the android back button the animations must work.

Any kind of help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. I used the medium [post](https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-navigating-off-the-charts-e118562a36a5) by Swav Kulinski which i pointed out in my question earlier.

The code is as follows,

```
class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavBarState createState() => _NavBarState();
}

class _NavBarState extends State<NavBar> {

  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  int currentIndex;
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    currentIndex = 0;
  }

  void changePage(int index) {
    navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(pagesRouteFactories.keys.toList()[index]);
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() {

    if(currentIndex == 3){
      changePage(2);
    } else if(currentIndex == 2){
      changePage(1);
    } else if(currentIndex == 1){
      changePage(0);
    } else if(currentIndex == 0){
      return Future.value(false);
    }

    return Future.value(true);
  }

  final pagesRouteFactories = {
    "/": () => MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Center(
        child: Text("HomePage",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,),
      ),
    ),
    "takeOff": () => MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Center(
        child: Text("Take Off",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,),
      ),
    ),
    "landing": () => MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Center(
        child: Text("Landing",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,),
      ),
    ),
    "settings": () => MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Center(
        child: Text("Settings",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,),
      ),
    ),
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: _buildBody(),
          bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNavigationBar(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() =>
      MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: (route) => pagesRouteFactories[route.name]()
      );

  Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar(context) => BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      _buildBottomNavigationBarItem("Home", Icons.home),
      _buildBottomNavigationBarItem("Take Off", Icons.flight_takeoff),
      _buildBottomNavigationBarItem("Landing", Icons.flight_land),
      _buildBottomNavigationBarItem("Settings", Icons.settings)
    ],
    currentIndex: currentIndex,
    onTap: changePage,
  );

  _buildBottomNavigationBarItem(name, icon) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(icon),
      title: Text(name),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
      activeIcon: Icon(icon)
  );
}
```

I do not know if this is the right approach though. If anyone want to suggest me better option please let me know.